# Finding anchor which having the same url as current url of a page

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, class, find, anchor

I've been thinking a while on how to add an active class on my sidebar menu by using jquery which will be filtered by url.

This is how I currently add the active class when the page is active :

```
<?php
  $seg1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
  $seg2 = $this->uri->segment(2);
  $seg3 = $this->uri->segment(3);
  $seg4 = $this->uri->segment(4);
?>

<li class="treeview <?php echo $seg1 == 'media' ? 'menu-open active' : '' ?>">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-image"></i><span>Media Library</span>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li class="<?php echo $seg1 == 'media' && $seg2 == 'images' ? 'menu-open active' : ''; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/images">Images</a>
      </li>
      <li class="<?php echo $seg1 == 'media' && $seg2 == 'videos' ? 'menu-open active' : ''; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/videos">Videos</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I'm thinking to do is getting the current page url by simple using the CI ready function `current_url()`, then find the anchor which is having the same url as the current url by using jquery. After do the comparison, I will get the parent `<li>` of the `<a>` and add the active class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily query elements by attribute comparison, like:

```
$('a[href="' window.location.href '"]').addClass('active');
```

Just put that inside your document ready scope/ event handler.

Comment: Great and simple solution. Thanks! :)